# Ошибки при установке пакетов с помощью pip3

Tags: python, lxml, pip

Здравствуйте! 
При установке пакетов pycurl и lxml (и не только этих пакетов)возникают следующие ошибки:

```
Downloading/unpacking pycurl
  Downloading pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz (182kB): 182kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py) egg_info for package pycurl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 103, in configure_unix
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in <module>
        ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in get_extension
        ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in __init__
        self.configure()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in configure_unix
        raise ConfigurationError(msg)
    __main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 103, in configure_unix

    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__

    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child

    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in <module>

    ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)

  File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in get_extension

    ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)

  File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in __init__

    self.configure()

  File "/tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in configure_unix

    raise ConfigurationError(msg)

__main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4raa300c/pycurl
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Помогите разобраться. (ОС - debian)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае (Debian) проблему (невозможность найти `curl-config`) может решить установка dev-пакетов `libcurl4-openssl-dev` и `libssl-dev`:

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev`

*P.S. Свою проблему решил таким же образом (помог [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937933/could-not-run-curl-config-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing)).*